# Create a MySQL parent / child relationship query for user logins

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with customer that I want to enable parent/child viewing permissions.

i.e. This is how I have established my data (I'm not sure if it is the best way to manage)

```
id        parent_id        name
1          5                Cust 1
2          5                Cust 2
3          6                Cust 3
4          6                Cust 4
5          0                Group Head
6          5                Sub Group
7          0                Cust 5
8          0                Cust 6
```

Therefore, the visual representation of this relationship is:

```
Group Head
 - Cust 1
 - Cust 2
 - Sub Group
   -- Cust 3
   -- Cust 4
```

I need to perform 2 checks on this relationship (which has brought me to this point of realising that I don't think I have the best structure...

1. First check, when 'Group Head' or 'Sub Group' logs in, I want to identify that they are a group so I can present them with an customer switching option
2. I need to perform a query to return all the Customers

i.e. If I login as 'Sub Group', it should return only Cust 3 & Cust 4 however, if I login as 'Group Head' it will return Cust 1, Cust 2, Cust 3 & cust 4 (Note: it excludes 'Sub Group' because it is a group, not a Customer)

For the first issue, I think I'll need another field that identifies as a Group or not?  Is this the best way?

For the second issue, I have built this query which I need to extend to also return the 'sub group' customers.

```
SELECT c.id, 
     c.parent_id, 
     c.name, 
FROM Customer c
WHERE c.parent_id = '5'
```

this returns:

```
id        parent_id        name
1          5                Cust 1
2          5                Cust 2
6          5                Sub Group
```

What I want the results to show:

`id        parent_id        name
1          5                Cust 1
2          5                Cust 2
3          6                Cust 3
4          6                Cust 4`

i.e. exclude the 'Sub Group' because it is not a customer AND show me the children of any of the selected that have children.

Note: I could settle to have the Sub Group displayed if I had to?

Comment: That depends on the complexity of your grouping. Is it always just 2 levels of grouping or you want to support also deeper levels `group - sub grp - sub sub group - ... - sub ... sub group`

Comment: Hi, at this stage I want to restrict it to 2 levels of grouping.

Answer (score 1):

Introduce at least type columns (and might be customer_type table for reference)

so let say group head is 1000, and sub group is 1500

filter customer with type smaller than 1000
so we can have enough space to expand later

Comment: I was thinking it would be inevitable to not avoid... I was hoping there was a way to not create 2 columns for this but every way I look at it, points me to this conclusion

Answer (score -1):

the child/parent logic is a little bit vague for me but I guess you could try

```
SELECT c.id, c.parent_id, c.name, 
  FROM Customer c
 WHERE c.parent_id = '5'
   AND c.id not in (5,6)
```

Here is the result

```
SELECT c.id, c.parent_id, c.name
  FROM ttest c
 WHERE c.parent_id in (5,6)
   AND c.id not in (5,6)


  ID  PARENT_ID NAME
---- ---------- ----------
   1          5 Cust 1
   2          5 Cust 2
   3          6 Cust 3
   4          6 Cust 4
```

Comment: That wont show id 3 & 4 because their parent_id = 6 and also, I need to be able to identify 5,6 programatically, not manually i.e. what can I use to identify them as Groups & not Customers